# Downloading all the products with all the variants and metafields from Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, shopify

Is there a way to download all the products with all the variants and metafields without having to perform 2 additional requests (1 for variant and 1 for metafields)? Maybe some sort of batch download?

This downloads a batch, however taking metafields and variants still require additional requests. Maybe some sort of includes?

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, ...).each
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download a product you get the variants without an extra call. Check your product variants attribute. Metafields are a completely separate resource, so you do indeed need to use an API call per resource where you want that resource's metafields.

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve all the metafields with products? I can't get all the data that I need because of the 429

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from getting all your data. There are clear instructions on using the API correctly with limits, and yes, you will receive a 429 when you exceed the allowed number of calls in 300 seconds. Please accept the answer provided as correct.

Comment: ShopifyAPI::Product.first.metafields.first.class.find(:all) - why this is returning []? I would like to do something like this: ShopifyAPI::Metafield.find(:all, ...) - for products, so I can get all the metafields for all the products. Is this possible?